# Css z-index is breaking by ngx-swiper(Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, swiper.js

I am using ng-swiper, for slide in phones views. I have one popup which have z-index property and its inside swiper tags. But swiper tags disturbs its z-index property. I am sharing stackblitz link for that

.[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination?)

If I am using same popup code under div without swiper tags then z-index of popup wokrs fine

Here's the image of the result I wanted (without disturbing x-axes flow)[image]

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [z-index](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) and everything to do with [overflow](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination-tgxhxg). Maybe you should take a step back from your high-end stack and learn the basics: inspecting, debugging, reading the spec...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu overflow, I already tried but it disturbed the x-flow also, the code which I put was just sample code. If you reduce the width of slides, you will see it disturbs everything, now width is 100%,so its showing overflow from x-axes side. overflow:-visible, can be solution but I dont recommend it to use since we can't do overflow-x:hidden and overflow-y:visible because of disadvantage of css.

Comment: perhaps you should have checked the links I provided.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  overflow:-visible, can be solution but I dont recommend it to use since we can't do overflow-x:hidden and overflow-y:visible. Although i tried your solution but no luck as you used overflow:visible.  Please check this and see how overflow:visible disturbs it .
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipper-pagination-4dvnfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I checked I know z-index can't be solution but same overflow:visible too. Although I didn't understand what you mean by reading the spec

Comment: So you want the tooltip to render outside of the slide and not render outside of the slide (`overflow:hidden`), at the same time, right?

Comment: My reference to documentation was an invitation to re-read the spec on z-index property. If you think `z-index` has anything to do with the tooltip not rendering outside your slide, you probably misunderstood how it works.

Comment: I updated my question with the picture, for z-index, I normally use position:absolute, relative, z-index:-1, 1